# Is there a site for app development job offers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site where it is welcome to post a request for questions like "Looking for app developers as contractors in Croatia"?

We are currently looking for some support in Kotlin native for app development.

Comment: What is *Kotlin native* / *Kotlin Native*?

Comment: **[Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276250/839601)**

Comment: @gnat I think it's just a badly named question. It's not exactly job offer (though the 'we are looking...' part is job-offer-like). The description is quite clearly asking for a site recommendation: it's asking whether such questions are acceptable anywhere.

Comment: @Chair the post I linked to explains how such questions will be accepted elsewhere (and yes, the title of this question almost made me flag it as spam)

Comment: @gnat Yep, your comment indicates that this is kind of a cross-site duplicate, because the same answer applies. But it does not indicate that this post is spam.

Comment: @PeterMortensen here we are:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native-overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Overflow sites, and the broader Stack Exchange network actually get a bunch of its revenue from [Job Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) - You might want to take a look at [SO Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) and see if it fits your needs, and help support the Q&A network at the same time.

<sub>Also, maaaan please don't call these forums.</sub>